# How high is the TLC5940?

Tags: datasheet, texas-instruments, dimensions

I've got some TLC5940 PDIP package ICs coming in the mail in a couple weeks or so, and in the meantime I'm designing a couple boards for them.

I'm trying to figure out if the TLC is short enough that I can stack another PCB on top using some headers, or if it's higher then a standard .1" header, but the datasheets aren't shedding any light on it.

The datasheet contains the dimensions of the 2 surface mount packages, but their missing the dimensions for the DIP package o.O

Link to the datasheet: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tlc5940.pdf

If anyone could shed some light on how high the TLC5940 is, that would be awesome!

Comment: Just find any other TI part in the same package. Most likely the TLC5940 package  will be exactly the same. If not it will be very close. You can also search the TI website for package drawings.

Comment: package drawings [here](http://www.ti.com/packaging/docs/searchtipackages.tsp?packageName=DIP)

Comment: @ThePhoton Thanks! I didn't realize that TI ICs had standard sizes. If you can turn that comment into an answer I'll accept it

Comment: Usually manufacturers will make an IC with 2 or 3 package options at least. You should poke around on the ti site more, like spend a couple of hours browsing on it and learn how to use it's features. Same goes for all those who are learning electronics. I spend a few hours a week poking around on digikey, analog.com, mouser, ti, linear ect. It would do your soul some good.

Comment: @KeithM found the data. updated answer.

Comment: @KeithM, Most new parts won't just conform to the manufacturer's standards, but to industry wide "JEDEC" standards (the IC makers mostly don't make the package themselves, they have their chips packaged by another company). This particular chip may be old enough (or odd-shaped enough) to not be a JEDEC standard package, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All information on the PDIP NT package seems to have disappeared from TI's website. **That package, and the PDIP version of the TLC5940 have been obsolete for years. It's no longer even mentioned on their website, and the latest data sheet, the one you link to, doesn't have it in the ordering information either.** It's 2015, DIP is dying a slow death.

<strike>Based on @ThePhoton's link, you can see that the max height for a DIP, metal or plastic, is 4.57 MM. Most are lower though, 4 MM max. 0.1" headers come in various heights, but 0.1" is 2.54 MM as a reference. Use 4.57 MM as your reference height for the DIP when designing your stacking board height.</strike>

Alternatively, just use some calipers to measure the package once they arrive.

Found an older version with the DIP data intact. [Data sheet from 2005.](http://www.zem.fr/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/TLC5940.pdf) It's a quite large 0.2"/5.08mm body.

[image]

Comment: Awesome! It'll fit under my 8mm headers then. Thanks :)

Comment: Yep, but if there are through-hole components mounted on the board above, you may have issues with coarsely clipped-off leads (anything 3mm or taller) interfering with the top of the DIP.  10mm is a more common board spacing but 8mm should be fine as long as there's nothing big above.